# Identify percent character match in R

Tags: string, r, match

I am looking to calculate the percent match for a string in R. For example:

```
x <- "asdf"     
y <- "fdjk"
```

I would like this to return .5 (e.g. 2 matches, irrespective of order). Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: will the strings always be of the same length? what if they are different?

Comment: they will not always be the same length; in that case, the denominator will the length of the longer vector.

Comment: And what would be the numerator if there where duplicate letters? ie "ab" and "aaabbb", or what about "aaaab" and "abbbb"? what are the right answers here?

Comment: Great followup; I'd like them to be unique such that for the first example it is 1/3 + 1/3 and for the second 1/4 + 1/4

Comment: So what is the rule you have that would result in those answers (2/3 and 1/2)?

Comment: I was doing unique() for each letter over the total number the times that letter appears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split up a string into its specific characters with `strsplit`:

```
char.x <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
char.x
# [1] "a" "s" "d" "f"
char.y <- strsplit(y, "")[[1]]
char.y
# [1] "f" "d" "j" "k"
```

Now, you can use `intersect` and `length` to compute your metric (the exact formula is not clear because your post didn't specify, for instance, how to handle duplicate characters):

```
length(intersect(char.x, char.y)) /
  max(length(unique(char.x)), length(unique(char.y)))
# [1] 0.5
```

Comment: BTW, if you do want to count dupes, (blowing my own horn again), the package `vecsets` will do intersections including duplicate elements.

Comment: You can use `strsplit` instead of `substring`: `strings <- sapply(list(x, y), strsplit, ""); 
intersect(strings[[1]], strings[[2]])`

Comment: @Jilber thanks -- `microbenchmark` tells me that's much faster than `substring`

Comment: What is the use of [[1]] next to the string